# Как собрать из 2-х отдельных программ одну программу на питон

Tags: python-3.x, menu

Я написала 2 отдельных программы на питоне. Теперь хочу сделать, чтобы через меню вызывалась то одна, то другая программа. Размер окна одинаковый, только визуальное представление (кнопки, поля ввода разные). Т.е. это как в ворде вызываешь один пункт меню выходит - один вид окна, вызываешь другой пункт меню - визуальное представление окна меняется. Как можно сделать также на питоне? 
2 программки называются test1.py и test2.py. Насколько я знаю в реализации меню на питоне можно подключить только команды (функции), а как подключить файлы?
Т.е. я имею ввиду такое меню:

```
menuBar = tkinter.Menu(win)
win.config(menu=menuBar)
Menu1 = tkinter.Menu(menuBar)
menuBar.add_cascade(label="Test2", menu=Menu1)
Menu1.add_command(label="Открыть", command=open)
```

Только фраза "command=open" не подходит, так как open это просто функция, а мне нужно чтобы открылся полностью 2-й файл программы со своим интерфейсом и отработали все функции в этом файле.

Comment: _как подключить файлы?_ - `from test1 import function_name` ?

Comment: вы не внимательно читали вопрос. функцию не надо, надо вызвать через меню весь файл 2-й программы

Comment: Вы можете сделать так, чтобы импортирование модуля вызвало исполнение его кода. Если они не написаны с использованием практики: `if __name__ == "__main__"`

Comment: тут другая проблема вылазит импортирование вызывает 2-ю программу и тогда первая программа не выполняется.

Comment: Этого нет в приведенном коде. Непонятно, в какой момент вы производите импорт.